# Prototype methods disappear when Socketio calls JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, serialization, socket.io

I'm trying to send an object with method's on its prototype using socketio. However these method's disappear when socketio internally calls JSON.stringify. My current idea is really tedious and does not seem correct. My current solution is as follows. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
/* ServerSide */

// Constructor Function
function Cons() {
  this.prop = 'property'
}
// Method on the prototype
Cons.prototype.func = function() {
  console.log('called')
}


io.on('connection', socket => {
  let obj =  new Cons() 
  obj = putMethodsOnTheObject(obj)
  obj = stringifyMethods(obj)
  io.emit('randomEvent', obj)
}

function putMethodsOnTheObject(obj) {
    for(let i in obj) {
        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            obj[i] = obj[i]; 
        }
    }
    return obj
}

function stringifyMethods(obj) {
 // Possibly toString each function and do some parsing?
}


/* ClientSide */

socket.on('randomEvent', obj => {
  obj = deStringifyMethods(obj) 
  console.log('obj: ', obj) 
}

function deStringifyMethods(obj) {
 // Possibly create a new function object for each func that was
 // converted to a string? like new Function(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are not blocked my socket.io issue, and actually you seem to be blocked by javascript stringify issue: `JSON.stringify` does not cover function stringify, it only stringify value members.

I found a third party lib which could help stringify function: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-fn, using the same lib, `stringify` in the server and `parse` in client side. I have not used yet, have a try and I think this could fix your issue.

e.g. in server side:

```
let jsonfn = require('json-fn')
let obj =  new Cons() 
obj = putMethodsOnTheObject(obj)
obj = jsonfn.stringify(obj)
io.emit('randomEvent', obj)
```

Good luck

Comment: But the problem is I wont be able to overwrite socketio's internal method right? Even if I use a library JSON.stringify will still be called by socketio

Comment: Nevermind. If I convert my object to a string using the 3rd party library I can recreate it on the front end using the same library. Ill check it out and let you know. Cheers

Comment: I updated my lib, to demostrate the idea I mentioned. you need to stringify it before using socket.io sending the obj. So 'YOU' control the content you want to send